# Custom alert on Receiving sms

Tags: android, notifications, sms

I am trying to write an application where I am intercepting in-coming sms.

That works fine.

Now when I am trying to set my own notification for it, it doesn't show.

Here is the code :

```
package sms;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

import com.pbc.connect2.StartActivity;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        this.abortBroadcast();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    showNotification("senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, "New Msg", context);

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }    

    private void showNotification(String eventtext, String Title, Context ctx) {
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Notification notification = new Notification(0,
                "Alert", System.currentTimeMillis());

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
        // notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                new Intent(ctx, StartActivity.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, Title, eventtext,
                contentIntent);
        notification.sound = alarmSound;
        notification.ledOnMS = 5;
        // Send the notification.
        notificationManager.notify("Title", 0, notification);
    }

}
```

I've debugged through the code and I see them executing. But the notification doesn't show.

The function showNotification() isn't working and all I get the system default notification. Where am I going wrong ?
Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to set an icon on your Notification?

Comment: ? I just cannot see the notification. No text nothing.

Comment: I ran a test with your code. It didn't show until I added an icon.

Comment: LOL :P Alright, I'll try with an icon tomorrow and let you know. Thanx for the information.

Comment: Ok. Also, you might use a Notification.Builder, too.